# PdoSessionHandler FOSUserBundle Login

Tags: session, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have implemented [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html) on saving the session into the database but the problem is the login didn't work after I've applied it with my App, it seems that it didnt get the entity based on this logs:

> [2014-02-26 05:47:10] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_user_security_check" (parameters: "_controller": "FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController::checkAction", "_route": "fos_user_security_check") [] []
>
> [2014-02-26 05:47:10] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
>
> [2014-02-26 05:47:10] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
>
> [2014-02-26 05:47:10] security.INFO: Authentication request failed: Invalid CSRF token. [] []
>
> [2014-02-26 05:47:10] security.DEBUG: Redirecting to /login [] []

as opposed to the default sessionhandler where it login just fine:

> [2014-02-26 07:10:07] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_user_security_check" (parameters: "_controller": "FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController::checkAction", "_route": "fos_user_security_check") [] []
>
> [2014-02-26 07:10:07] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
>
> [2014-02-26 07:10:07] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
>
> [2014-02-26 07:10:07] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.username AS username1, t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical2, t0.email AS email3, t0.email_canonical AS email_canonical4, t0.enabled AS enabled5, t0.salt AS salt6, t0.password AS password7, t0.last_login AS last_login8, t0.locked AS locked9, t0.expired AS expired10, t0.expires_at AS expires_at11, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token12, t0.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at13, t0.roles AS roles14, t0.credentials_expired AS credentials_expired15, t0.credentials_expire_at AS credentials_expire_at16, t0.id AS id17, t0.first_name AS first_name18, t0.last_name AS last_name19, t0.date_created AS date_created20 FROM Users t0 WHERE t0.username_canonical = ? LIMIT 1 ["rainercedric23"] []
>
> [2014-02-26 07:10:07] security.INFO: User "rainercedric23" has been authenticated successfully [] []

as you can see the logs shows that there's no interaction with doctrine with the PdoSessionHandler compared to the default session handler. I also noticed after the form has been submitted the listener can't get the CSRF token that makes the authentication request failed.

UPDATE:

This is the logs without CSRF token, It authenticates the user but after it leaves the page it writes another session in the database which makes the next page user token anonymous again:

> [2014-02-26 07:39:59] security.INFO: User "rainercedric23" has been authenticated successfully [] []
>
> [2014-02-26 07:39:59] security.DEBUG: Read SecurityContext from the session [] []
>
> [2014-02-26 07:39:59] security.DEBUG: Reloading user from user provider. [] []
>
> [2014-02-26 07:39:59] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.username AS username1, t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical2, t0.email AS email3, t0.email_canonical AS email_canonical4, t0.enabled AS enabled5, t0.salt AS salt6, t0.password AS password7, t0.last_login AS last_login8, t0.locked AS locked9, t0.expired AS expired10, t0.expires_at AS expires_at11, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token12, t0.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at13, t0.roles AS roles14, t0.credentials_expired AS credentials_expired15, t0.credentials_expire_at AS credentials_expire_at16, t0.id AS id17, t0.first_name AS first_name18, t0.last_name AS last_name19, t0.date_created AS date_created20 FROM Users t0 WHERE t0.id = ? LIMIT 1 [7] []
>
> [2014-02-26 07:39:59] security.DEBUG: Username "rainercedric23" was reloaded from user provider. [] []
>
> [2014-02-26 07:40:00] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
>
> [2014-02-26 07:40:00] security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
>
> [2014-02-26 07:40:00] security.DEBUG: Access is denied (user is not fully authenticated)
>
> [2014-02-26 07:40:00] security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point [] []

any ideas on how to solve it? thanks!~

Comment: csrf protection kicks in here: `Authentication request failed: Invalid CSRF token.` Check wether the session was started correctly using `$session->isStarted()`. btw. did you clear all caches AND your browser cache ?

Comment: yup I clear all the cache and the browser cache.. and also the $session->isStarted() returns true when I dump it... I also try to disable the csrf token and makes the authentication successful, but the next problem is that when he goes to the home page after successful authentication, the homepage creates another session(Only in PDOSessionHandler but in default sessionhandler it doesnt create another session) in which the token becomes unauthenticated again and it redirects me to login again.

Comment: So basically the session-handler doesn't pick up previous sessions and therefore creates new ones for every request?

Comment: basically that's what I see from the logs it give. I'll update my question to see the complete logs without csrf token.

Comment: The logs are clear about this. The session gets created again on every new request. That's enough. Did you change anything else? like override the session-handler?

Comment: I didnt change anything else I've just use the PdoSessionHandler in Symfony... But I think overriding it is the solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution by creating a customPdoSessionHandler in my Bundle thanks to Daniel15 from [this](http://webdevrefinery.com/forums/topic/3357-pdo-session-handler/)(I've tweak some codes to be able to use it in Symfony2), I've made the PdoSessionHandler as a basehandler for my customPdoSessionHandler

```
<?php

namespace foo\barBundle\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler as baseHandler;

/**
 * PDO Session Handler
 * @author Daniel15 <dan.cx>
 *
 * This class is actually static, but since PHP doesn't support static classes, abstract is close
 * enough. You do not instantiate the class; you just call the static "init" method.
 */
class CustomPdoSessionHandler extends baseHandler {

    private static $db;
private static $oldData;
private $pdo;
private $dbOptions;

public function __construct(\PDO $pdo, array $dbOptions = array())
{

    if (!array_key_exists('db_table', $dbOptions)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('You must provide the "db_table" option for a PdoSessionStorage.');
    }
    if (\PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION !== $pdo->getAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('"%s" requires PDO error mode attribute be set to throw Exceptions (i.e. $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION))', __CLASS__));
    }

    $this->pdo = $pdo;
    $this->dbOptions = array_merge(array(
        'db_id_col'   => 'session_id',
        'db_data_col' => 'data',
        'db_time_col' => 'last_activity',
    ), $dbOptions);
}



/**
 * Session open handler
 * @param string Path to save session to
 * @param string Name of the session
 */
public function open($save_path, $session_name) {
    // Nothing
    return true;
}

/**
 * Session close handler
 */
public function close() {
    // Nothing
    return true;
}

/**
 * Session load handler. Load the session
 * @param string Session ID
 */
public function read($session_id) {
    // Load Table from the database
    $dbTable   = $this->dbOptions['db_table'];
    $dbDataCol = $this->dbOptions['db_data_col'];
    $dbIdCol   = $this->dbOptions['db_id_col'];
    // Load the session data from the database
    $query = $this->pdo->prepare("
        SELECT $dbDataCol
        FROM $dbTable
        WHERE $dbIdCol = :session_id");
    $query->execute(array(':session_id' => $session_id));

    return $query->fetchColumn();
}

/**
 * Session save handler. Save the session
 * @param string Session ID
 * @param string Data to save to session
 */
public function write($session_id, $data) {

    //load table form the database
    $dbTable   = $this->dbOptions['db_table'];
    $dbDataCol = $this->dbOptions['db_data_col'];
    $dbIdCol   = $this->dbOptions['db_id_col'];
    $dbTimeCol = $this->dbOptions['db_time_col'];

    /* Try to update the existing session. If we can't find one, then create a new one. If you
     * are using MySQL, this can be done in a single INSERT statment via INSERT ... ON 
     * DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Remove the UPDATE and edit the INSERT to do it this way.
     * See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html
     *
     * This does two queries so you can use any DBMS.
     */

    $query = $this->pdo->prepare("
        UPDATE $dbTable
        SET $dbDataCol = :data, last_activity = :last_activity
        WHERE $dbIdCol = :session_id");
    $query->execute(array(
        ":session_id" => $session_id,
        ":data" => $data,
        "$dbTimeCol" => time()));

    // No session to update? Create a new one
    if ($query->rowCount() == 0) {
        $query = $this->pdo
                ->prepare('
                INSERT INTO sessions
                    (session_id, data, last_activity)
                VALUES
                    (:session_id, :data, :last_activity)')
                ->execute(array(
                    ':session_id' => $session_id,
                    ':data' => $data,
                    'last_activity' => time())
        );
    }
}

/**
 * Session delete handler. Delete the session from the database
 * @param string Session ID
 */
public function destroy($session_id) {
    //Load Table from the database
    $dbTable   = $this->dbOptions['db_table'];
    $dbIdCol   = $this->dbOptions['db_id_col'];

     $this->pdo
            ->prepare("
            DELETE FROM $dbTable
            WHERE $dbIdCol = :session_id")
            ->execute(array(':session_id' => $session_id));
}

/**
 * Session garbage collector. Delete any old expired sessions
 * @param int How many seconds do sessions last for?
 */
public function gc($lifetime) {
    //Load Table from the database
    $dbTable   = $this->dbOptions['db_table'];
    $dbTimeCol = $this->dbOptions['db_time_col'];

    $this->pdo
            ->prepare("
            DELETE FROM $dbTable
            WHERE $dbTimeCol < :min_time")
            ->execute(array(':min_time' => time() - $lifetime));
}

}
```

and modified the class in the config.yml:

```
framework:
    session:
        handler_id:  session.handler.pdo
services:
    pdo:
        class: PDO
        arguments:
            dsn:      "mysql:dbname=dev_reporting_system"
            user:     root
            password: null
        calls:
            - [setAttribute, [3, 2]] # \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    session.handler.pdo:
        class:     foor\barBundle\Handler\CustomPdoSessionHandler
        arguments: ["@pdo", "%pdo.db_options%"]
```

Hope it helps others :D